# UIScrollView delaying when scroll

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout

I use UIScrollView for horizontal scrolling first image is ok (see below image)
[image: first image]

and when start sliding the image didn't fit (see below image)
[image: second image]

and also next image the image shifting more (see below)

[image: third image]

and each image slide the shifting increase; below is last image

[image: last image]

i use auto layout as below

[image: autolayout]

i don't know where the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Select your imageview and check property 'Clip Subviews' from Attribute Inspector then run your code, that will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but I didn't put image view only scrollView inside Uiview

Comment: Then how you displayed images on scrollView ?

Comment: Programming an imageView

Comment: ok, add one extra line  imageView.clipsToBounds = YES. It should work.

Comment: and keep the constrain as its?

Comment: Yes, leave constraint as they are. You can scroll till end, that means constraint for scrollView is working fine.